# Doctrine 2 preFlush Event Add Associated Class

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to add a user entity to an entity on the preFlush event.  Basically each entity has a createdBy which is a User entity.

Whenever I try this I receive the following error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: 0000000055f036b6000000009c9cc58f in /dir/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 870
```

This is my preFlush function.

```
public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') 
        || $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'))
    {
        $user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    }
    if(!$user)
    {
        $user = $em->getRepository('NAB\EnterpriseBundle\Entity\User')->findOneByUsername($this->username);
    }
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity)
    {
        $entity->setCreatedBy($user);
        $em->persist($user);

    }
    $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
    $uow->computeChangeSets($meta, $entity);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this `preFlush()` a lifecycle event on your entity? Or what is the bigger context? I'm curious because I need to do something similar, but don't know how to tie it all together. I didn't think the entity manager was available in the entity itself? I've never done a lifecycle event or an event listener so I don't know how they should interact with my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are computing changesets incorrectly. Following bit:

```php
$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
$uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
$uow->computeChangeSets($meta, $entity);
```

Is executed only on the last entity in the checked context.

You should instead move it to your foreach:

```php
foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
    $entity->setCreatedBy($user);
    $em->persist($user);

    $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
}
```

Even better (since you are not familiar with the `UnitOfWork` API), you could recompute all changesets once at the end only:

```php
foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
    $entity->setCreatedBy($user);
    $em->persist($user);
}

$uow->computeChangeSets();
```

You should also move this listener from `preFlush` to `onFlush` to handle any changes applied by other listeners.

Comment: In what context would you use this code to computeChangeSets? Is this on a lifecycle event function on the entity? Or a separate event listener? If so, how does the controller register this?

Comment: Typically on an external event listener: entities and controllers have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes @Ocramius is correct, this was in a subscriber.